# Cannot import mediapipe in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mediapipe

I am trying to import mediapipe in Jupyter but it seems that my mediapipe version does not have audio_classifier

I have try to reinstall the newest version of tensorflow 2.12.0 but it still does not work

This is my code:

> ```
> !pip install tensorflow==2.12.0 tensorflow-gpu==2.12.0 opencv-python mediapipe sklearn matplotlib
> ```
>
> ```
> import mediapipe as mp
> ```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To get relevant answers faster I would suggest to post error messages as text that you can cut and paste from console, not as images.