# Cannot import mediapipe - TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, typeerror, mediapipe

The install is successful.  I receive this error when trying to import.

```
TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

[image]

I have tried higher and lower versions of numpy (1.22.0,1.23.0,1.24.0,1.25.0,1.25.2). I installed mediapipe via pypi as well as a downloaded whl ( `mediapipe-0.10.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`) from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/0.10.3/#files)

Versions

```
numpy                        1.21.5
mediapipe                    0.10.3

Python 3.10.6
```

These questions are similar but not the answer.

[Importing xarray raises not subscriptable issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596440/importing-xarray-raises-not-subscriptable-issue)

[Cannot import mediapipe in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76252065/cannot-import-mediapipe-in-jupyter-notebook)

[How to prevent error message when importing import cv2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879942/how-to-prevent-error-message-when-importing-import-cv2)

Comment: Well I would go with upgrading numpy first and check if this works.

Comment: Also what OS are you using?

Comment: Restarting the kernel works with what you have tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating `numpy` to 1.23 works. I was not restarting the kernel after installing versions of `numpy`. With notebook-scoped libraries, use `dbutils.library.restartPython()`. If you are using cluster-scoped libraries, then be sure to restart your cluster.

There's an issue about this that's documented on the OpenCV repo here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23822
In short, it imported successfully with most `numpy>=1.22.0` versions.
Just be careful, if you use some of the most recent library versions, like `numpy>=1.25.0`, you start running into other compatibility issues.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error while importing CV2. For this, use 1.20.0 version of numpy.

```
pip install numpy==1.20.0
```

Comment: `pip install numpy==1.23.0` worked for me

Comment: Don't forget to restart the kernel if trying to import in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem when installing OpenCV(2) for PyAutoGUI. Specifically, I tried to use PyAutoGUI's locateOnScreen feature, and it told me that I needed OpenCV for the confidence parameter.

I installed OpenCV with `pip install opencv-python`, then tried importing PyAutoGUI again.

It threw an error that traced to OpenCV, similar to what the OP encountered:

> TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable.

I had previously messed with numpy for machine learning, and I believe that was the issue; running `pip install numpy==1.23.0` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in 2 steps:

```
1. !pip install numpy --upgrade 
2. Restart the kernel
```

Now, everything worked like a charm. Special thanks to gruvw.